How to crop viewable website area using webview_flutter package?
I am making an app, and I am experimenting with the WebView_flutter package. I want to have a website shown in multiple screens in my app. My issue is that when I use WebView, it displays the whole website. How do I go about cropping the viewable area? I only want the top half of the website displayed, and everything else discarded. Many thanks in advance.
Code for the WebView widget:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebPage> createState() => _WebPageState();
}

class _WebPageState extends State<WebPage> {
  final WebViewController _controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('myChosenWebsiteHere.com'))
    ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.black);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller,)
            ),
        )
        ],),
      )
    );
  }
}

Here is the Container() I am using to hold the WebView widget:
        Container(
            height: 500,
            child: WebPage(),
          ),

Here are some pictures better describing exactly what I would want to achieve:
What I have currently:

And here is what I need to achieve:

